# ''Customized'' or what?

Tags: word-choice

I'm planning to hire a car with driver from tourist agency and have one day trip or multi-day tour. They have their own tour packages with standard destinations and itineraries. But I want to make my own routes and itineraries or order other destinations which is not included in their standard packages. 
Can I call it ''customized tour''?. 
So I mean - can I call ''Customized tour'' when I want to order my desired destinations with my interesting routes and itineraries which is not included their standard packages?. 
Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Yes "customized tour" properly communicates what you are asking for. Many tour services will have a package for that which they often call "customized" or "personalized" tour packages..

Comment: Isn't that more often termed a *tailored package*?

Answer (score 1):

A custom tour, personalized tour, or a customized tour all describe your service. Personal tour also works- or a combination, 'custom personal tours'.